# Why does this ForEach loop keep causing an error?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I'm having an issue with this ForEach loop. I'm trying to get it to loop through an array but it keeps giving an unknown error which says 'Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report and include the project'. When I delete the ForEach loop, the error goes away.

This is the file that's giving the error

```
struct ReceiptView: View {

let item: ItemsStruct

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        // Header
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.company)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                Text(item.date)
                    .font(.caption)
            }
            Spacer()
            Menu {
                Text("Menu Item 1")
                Text("Menu Item 2")
                Text("Menu Item 3")
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                    .scaleEffect(1.2)
            }
        }.padding()
        
        
        // FIXME: This ForEach is causing an error
        ForEach(item.products) { prod in
            Text(prod.product)
        }

    }
}
```

}

And This is the ItemsStruct:

```
public struct ItemsStruct: Identifiable {
    public let id = UUID()
    let company: String
    let date: String
    let total: String
    let products: [itemsArray]

    struct itemsArray {
        let product: String
        let quantity: Int
        let totalPrice: Double
    }

}
```

Any thoughts on what's causing this error?

Comment: Your `ItemsArray` struct does not conform to `Identifiable`.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. Can't believe I missed that

Comment: perhaps ProductOrder would be a better name for the type "itemsArray" - the name is not plural, it's not an array, and swift types are named with a capital letter

Comment: I agree. But I'm just one of those that picks whatever comes to mind first. Thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another Identifiable

```
public struct ItemsStruct: Identifiable {
    
    public let id: UUID = UUID()
    let company: String
    let date: String
    let total: String
    let products: [ItemsArray]
    
}

struct ItemsArray: Identifiable {
    
    let id: UUID = UUID()          // <<: Here!
    let product: String
    let quantity: Int
    let totalPrice: Double
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it

Comment: you are welcome, I just corrected **itemsArray** to **ItemsArray** it should be capital, and maybe even better naming would not be a bad idea.

Comment: I was aware of that typo but just never got round to changing it. Thanks